# suspend thread for a second in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, time, sleep

how can I sleep for 1s in a C app?
I want to disconnect a socket, so I want to sleep for a second and trigger the timeout. In Java it's

> Thread.sleep(1000);

Thanks a lot

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What does sleeping have to do with disconnecting a socket? Just close it.

Answer (score 5):

The C specification doesn't really cover threads, so you'll need a platform specific one.

- The POSIX function [sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html).
- Or Windows [sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) - sleep for the specified number of seconds.

[usleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) - suspend execution for microsecond intervals.

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
int usleep(useconds_t usec);
```

sleep takes arguments in seconds whereas usleep takes in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are on Linux.

Please read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You want to use the `sleep(3)` function (or the `nanosleep(2)` syscall).

You probably need to learn also about multiplexing syscalls like `poll(2)`

See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) man page.